# Ionic Reactive Form - Changes the url when submitting

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

so basically, i created a form to submit a new client, but after clicking on the submit button, it just changes the url to the inputs and it does not log my inputs in the console? Is there a major problem i make?

This is my form in the create-client.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="createClientForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-label color="primary">Firmenname</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Firmenname" class="primary-input" required></ion-input>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-label color="primary">Anschrift</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="streetAndNr" placeholder="Straße und Nr." class="primary-input" required></ion-input>
    <ion-input formControlName="location" placeholder="Ort" class="primary-input" required></ion-input>
    <ion-input formControlName="plz" placeholder="PLZ" class="primary-input" required></ion-input>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-label color="primary">Telefonnummer</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="phonenr" placeholder="Telefonnummer" class="primary-input" required></ion-input>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-label color="primary">E-Mail</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="primary-input" required></ion-input>
  </ion-card>

  <br>

  <div class="ion-margin-top">
    <ion-button type="submit" expand="block">Fertig</ion-button>
  </div>

  <div class="ion-margin-top ion-text-center">
    <a (click)="dismiss()">Abbrechen</a>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

and this is my submitForm method:

```
createClientForm!: FormGroup;
isFormSubmitted = false;

submitForm(){
    this.isFormSubmitted = true;

    console.log(this.createClientForm.value);
  }
```

my url basically changes to something like this:

```
http://localhost:8100/home?ion-input-0=asasd&ion-input-1=asd&ion-input-2=asd&ion-input-3=asd&ion-input-4=asd&ion-input-5=asd
```

Comment: `createClientForm` in undefined. That is obvious. Are you at least making a minimal effort to look at your code? This type of question is asked at least 5 times a day on SO. Try doing a search before posting.

Comment: Sorry, i am pretty new to programming, so i make this basic mistakes..